# Identifier already declared

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

```
event transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval (address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor(){
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply; 
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view   returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];  
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public  returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] +=value;
        balances[msg.sender] -=value;
        emit transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
```

I get this error when trying to compile a contract in remix:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. --> Token.sol:23:5: | 23 | 
function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) { | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines). Note: The previous declaration is here: --> Token.sol:12:5: | 12 | event transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value); | 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi! The error you posted mentions a line that isn't present in your code - it says you also have an event called `transfer`. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your event and function transfer have the same name. Change your function name.